# Prevent event bubbling in Material UI when Select Dropdown when clicking away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, material-ui, dom-events

I have a div with a Checkbox and a Select dropdown (which uses a ClickAwayListener, not sure if relevant).

I am allowed to click on anywhere in this div to change the checkbox, except for the Select, which should not change the checkbox and instead open, close and select and item without touching the checkbox.

The issue is even with all the code in to prevent event bubbling, the checkbox is still changing as I attempt to close the select. If I am interacting at all with the select, I do not want the checkbox to change. How can I fix this?

Here is a demo illustrating the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fast-qll47?file=/src/App.js

This gif also shows what exactly is going on:
[image]

To recreate it, see how one can open the Dropdown without changing the checkbox.

Now, close the dropdown by clicking outside of the div. You will see that the checkbox changes. This should not happen.
Once the dropdown is opened either if I select an item or close it by clicking elsewhere, the checkbox should not change.

Anyway, what can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm my best guess is that, the `Select` component is forwarding the `click` event from the backdrop to the `Select` component when you click outside the select.

Since you only catch the `blur` event, also catching the `click` event should do the trick.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dream-iy3d2?file=/src/App.js